# .XLSM file has sharing violation when saving during remote desktop use

Tags: microsoft-excel, remote-desktop, macros

I have a large (~5mb) multi sheet excel macro file *.xlsm stored locally on my laptop. While using the file I occasionally connect to my office via remote desktop to do unrelated work. If I make a change to the sheet with a macro, then try and save the file locally *while incidentally connected to remote desktop*, I get the sharing violation shown below. If I make text changes only, and try to save while RDP is running, I get no errors. Also, if RDP is not running at all, I can save after text or macro changes. How do I prevent this error?

```
“Your changes could not be saved to DD.xlsm because of a sharing violation. Try saving to a different file.”
```

Comment: Does your remote desktop connection involve any sort of VPN or additional remote access technology?  Or is it established by running the RDC client **only**?

Comment: RDC client only.

Comment: If you create a brand new Excel workbook and create in it a new macro, can you reproduce this behavior? I want to know if this behavior is specific to this workbook or to any workbook with a similar macro.

Comment: Ok I will check. Probably will get back to you early next week.